# ASP.NET 4 URL routing with web forms and numerous products

Tags: asp.net, webforms

We are about to start development of an e-commerce site that will lean heavily on the new .net 4 url routing [see ScottGu's blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/13/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx). The potential problem I see is that we have 1000's of products to display and each one will have its own unique URL. My question is this: Does anyone have experience registering the routes of 1000's of products in Application_Start? How does this effect performance? Memory usage? Other issues I'm not even aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why wouldn't you route it [like this image](http://weblogs.asp.net/blogs/scottgu/step2_5866151D.png), where the product name is a slug?

Since the product is a slug, not part of the routed URL, and you can access which product was requested through the [routing data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.routedata.aspx)...

Comment: Yes, that's right, I wasn't thinking this through the right way. Thanks.